# Cut videos from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, video-processing

I have a web app that is hosted in Azure; one of it's functionalities is to be able to make a few cuts from the video(generate 2 or 3 small videos of 5-10 seconds from a larger video).
The videos are persisted in Azure Blob Storage.

How do you suggest to accomplish this in the Azure environment?
The actual cutting of the videos will be initiated by a web job. I'm also concerned about the pricing(within the Azure environment), I'm taking into account the possibility of high traffic.

Any feedback is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have video-cutting code that operates on files through normal I/O: You'd need to download the video file from blob, process it via code (or whatever library you've employed), and then store the result back in blob storage. You cannot reference a blob directly with normal standard IO libraries.

If, however, videos are stored in Azure File storage (which is an SMB layer on top of blob storage, then you *will* be able to directly manipulate your video files.

Web Jobs run within an App Service (just like Web Apps), so you have access to a certain amount of local disk space (depending on App Service tier) for use. You should have no problem temporarily storing a video file within your web app's disk space, for editing operations.

You asked about cost: Again, assuming you're talking about running code within a Web Job (app service), you're just paying for whatever App Service tier you've chosen.

How you actually do those edit operations is entirely up to you (language, library, etc).

Comment: It's a really good idea David, thanks, I'll try a quick POC and get back with feedback.

Comment: Just a quick observation, it's possible I will have a problem with the local disk space, because I have large files and sometimes a few web jobs will do the same operation at the same time. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: I don't know how you define "large files." But... with web apps, you can have up to 50GB storage (standard tier) or 250GB storage (premium tier). If you feel that's not enough, you can always consider moving your processing to a VM, which has considerable capability just in temporary storage alone (depending on chosen tier), and also support attaching 2 1TB disks per core.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Blob Storage is simply an object store which stores the data. It does not have the capability you're looking for.

[`Azure Media Service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/media-services/) however is the service you should look into. The media served by this service makes use of Azure Blob Storage.

For editing video, may I suggest you take a look at `Video Editor Plugin` for Azure Media Player. You can read more about this plugin here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/video-editor-plugin/. You can also try it out here: http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/amp_editor.html.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I should have been more detailed in my question. The actual cutting of the videos will be initiated by a web job. I'm also concerned about the pricing, I'm taking into account the possibility of high traffic.

Comment: I'm afraid I am not so much versed with video editing libraries. You may want to look for such libraries that can be included in your WebJob code so that videos can be edited programmatically. If such libraries are installable software, then you may want to look into Worker Roles or go with Virtual Machines and have the software install there. But I agree with you that Media Services can be expensive solution.