# Referencing data in blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have set up a postgreSQL database on a linux VM in Azure, and I have a .csv file in blob storage that I'd like to upload to that database.

However, I can't find any documentation regarding how (or even if it's possible) to reference files that are stored in blob storage as if it were part of the file system, or otherwise transfer files from blob storage to a server also running in Azure.

All the references I've found are about importing directly into pre-built SQL Server VMs, which is not my problem.

Any references or other help anyone can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: Blob service is the right way to store files in Azure. Why do you want to move it to another service / server? I think you just need to store the endpoint into some table in your postgreSQL

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I don't really want to store it anywhere else, I just want to know how to reference it for ingestion into the postgreSQL DB. I have the table created, but I don't know how to reference/move the data for upload into my table.

Comment: This has been addressed in numerous places and answers (such as a recent one I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42556761/272109)) - you need to copy it to local storage (e.g. local disk on your VM) before you can open it with standard I/O libraries. And plenty of docs for copying a blob from azure storage to disk (every published language SDK supports this, along with PowerShell and CLI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the PostgreSQL support program key word in its query.

So I suggest you could use this key word to access the blob storage csv file.

Normally we will use curl to access the file, you could download it in below url:
https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Linux

More details, you could refer to follow example codes:

```
COPY persons(first_name,last_name,dob,email) 
FROM PROGRAM 'C:\curl "https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/test2.csv?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=jtNRuzR7G98hHogHHZyKY9gYN0r%2FSgr2j78HGKihYlc%3D&st=2017-03-09T02%3A43%3A17Z&se=2017-03-11T02%3A43%3A17Z&sp=rl"'DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

The result of the query like as below:

[image]

Here I used the SAS token to protect my blob file.

If you don’t want to use this token, you could set the container’s permission in the portal.

Like below:
[image]

Then you could directly access the file by the url.
Link this : 
https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/test2.csv

If you want to use the SAS token to protect my blob file, you could generate the SAS token as below images shows:

[image]

The result is like this
[image]

Then you could add this token behind the access blob url.

More details, you could refer to follow link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, that worked perfectly!